# What is the simplest way to write/maintain a specification document?

Tags: project-management, specifications

I'm working in a start up where documentation has the lowest priority. The reasons that are given to me for that is that start up companies won't usually invest lot of time in documentations and how-tos. So at the start of each project I get very less time to document the features/specifications/behavior of the system I'm going to write.

In most of the cases even if I prepare a initial document, the requirements keep evolving and the behavior of the system changes slightly during development. Moreover I work in a product based company and hence we come up with our own requirements which definitely undergoes some changes during development.

So my question is what is the simplest possible representation of a system's specifications/behaviors? How can I easily write one and update it regularly without spending much time (writing tons of lines in it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requirement specifications make more sense when you have a fixed project lifecycle.  What you are describing sounds a lot like an iterative project life cycle and Agile project management is much better suited to it.  In agile project management, requirements are managed as user stories.  A user story is a simple way of describing a requirement in this format:

> As a (role) I want (something) so that
>   (benefit)

for example, for a shopping cart app, one user story can be:

> As a registered user I want to add a
>   listed product to the cart so that i
>   can order it.

With each iteration, you can go back and see if you need to add a new user story or modify an existing one.  For starters, you can keep user stories in a spreadsheet (one per row) but many other advanced agile pm packages are available both for online and offline use.